# How do you say "hot chocolate" in spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

It is clear that a literal translation yields *"chocolate caliente,"* but is this the correct translation for hot chocolate?

Comment: You can say "un chocolate" and people will assume you mean a hot chocolate. If you are ever in Spain, you should definitely try "un chocolate con churros" (delicious!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original translation is accurate:

> hot chocolate = chocolate caliente

Answer (score 2):

You can also say "chocolate a la taza"

Comment: En qué país se usa ese término?

Comment: En España (juzgando por el perfil de rafabayona). Pero sospecho que aún en España es un localismo en este momento. Si lo he leído en publicaciones españolas de los años 50 a 70.

Comment: Sí, al menos en España es un término bien vivo. Google arroja más de un millón de resultados.

Answer (score 2):

In Mexico, a lot of people simply say "chocolate", although it can be misinterpreted easily. If you say something like "chocolate con pan", it's always interpreted as hot chocolate.

Comment: In Chile is the same.